# Mysql Mathematics on the fly

Tags: mysql

I am doing a migration from one database structure to another where there are rating values in a column.

In database table A the rating is 0-10 in database table B the rating is from 0-4.

I would like to select all values from TABLE A and convert the value from a 0-10 to a 0-4 EG. if the value in A is 5 then it would become 2 and so forth. The resulting value would need to be a single decimal place.

Thanks

Comment: value a / 10 = x/4 to 1 decimal place solve for x

Comment: Are Table A values integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you calculate the factor is `10 / 4 = 2.5`

So if column A are integer you will have 1 decimal

```
 SELECT columnA / 2.5
 FROM TableA
```

otherwise

```
 SELECT CAST( columnA / 2.5 AS DECIMAL (2,1) )
 FROM TableA
```

Comment: So were A integers or not?

Comment: Yes they were integers